# discord.py waiting for message object error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am utilising the wait_for_response on the discord.py async library however, my code

```
await self.Nao.say("What is your name? (Cannot exceed over 100 characters)")
usrname = await self.Nao.wait_for_message(author=ctx.message.author)
await self.Nao.say("What is your Age? (Cannot exceed over 100 characters)")
usrage = await self.Nao.wait_for_message(author=ctx.message.author)
```

for some reason returns `<discord.message.Message object at 0x7f88d8de2788>` in the bots response `await self.Nao.say(usrname + usrage)

Comment: Reread the documentation for `wait_for_message`.  It returns a `Message` object, not a string.

Comment: Did you get it or do you still need assistance with this question? I think @PatrickHaugh answered it...

Comment: This has been solved. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Using rewrite, using a `wait_for` can be used as shown below. A wait for can also pass "check" arguments that are required, below, it requires the same author to be able to answer the wait for, then a timeout. The "lambda" function allows easy utilization of this function.

```
msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=10, check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)

   if msg.content.lower() == "yes":
       await ctx.send("Great!")

   if msg.content.lower() == "no":
       await ctx.send("Cancelled!")
```